# Convert Keys and Values of a HashMap into a HTML-Table with java

Tags: java, hashmap, html-table

I have a `HashMap` which looks like the following:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> jcbs = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

The key is a `String`, the Value an `Integer`.

Now I have a html-file in which there is a table.

What I need to do now, is to fill all the keys and values of the `HashMap` into this html table.

Comment: can u give more details? where is the HashMap
client side server side? what programming language.

Comment: why have you selected key as string?

Comment: My HashMap is client side - the programming language is java

Comment: And the point, why i've selected a String as key, is because my second field is a counter, and so the key cant be an Integer, because there could be the same counter twice as key, and that would lead to an error or something i think

Answer (score 1):

```
<%

    StringBuilder stringMapTable = new StringBuilder();
    stringMapTable.append("<table>");

    Iterator it = jcbc.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            stringMapTable.append("<tr><td>" + entry.getKey() + "</td><td>" +entry.getValue() + "</td></tr>");
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }

  String mapTable = stringMapTable.toString();

%>
```

In HTML

```
<%=mapTable %>
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate and display the hashmap in a html page in either jsp or jsf can be done in the following ways:

In case of JSP , use jstl :

Map books = new HashMap();

```
<c:forEach var="booksVar" items="${books}">
    Book Id: ${books.key} , Capital: ${books.value}
</c:forEach>
```

This can be easily used with Native html table code.

Answer (score 1):

With advent of java8 , we can create the html table in pure java by using stream api .

```
    final Map<String,Integer> map =  new HashMap<>();
    
    map.put("key1", 5);
    map.put("key2", 7);
    
    String tableBody =
    map.keySet()
       .stream()
       .map(item -> new StringBuilder("<tr><td>")
                                     .append(item)
                                     .append("</td><td>")
                                     .append(String.valueOf(map.get(item)))
                                     .append("</td></tr>")
       )
       .collect(Collectors.joining());
    
    String tableContent = "<table>" + tableBody + "</table>";
    
    System.out.println("tableContent = "+tableContent);
```

To create a table in jsp from a map , better opt for JSTL.

```
    <table>
        <c:forEach var="entry" items="${mapObj}">
            <tr><td>${entry.key}</td> <td><${entry.value}</td></tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as this:

```
StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
htmlBuilder.append("<table>");

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    htmlBuilder.append(String.format("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%d</td></tr>",
            entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}

htmlBuilder.append("</table>");

String html = htmlBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: I've implemented this into my programm, but is isnt working.
My question is: where do I have to specify the directory, where this html has to be written to?

Comment: Are you just looking to write output to a file? I'm sure Google can help you with that.

Comment: Yes thats what i want to do: I have my HashMap, already filled with data, and I just have to generate an HTML with a table inside it, and fill all the keys and values into this table

Comment: I gave you the code to generate the HTML. The rest you can find e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file